# Using groovy map for DSL with invalid keys

Tags: groovy, dsl

I'm currently building a small DSL, which needs to specify a set of properties in key=value pairs, however the keys may contain dashes '-' or periods '.' and I can't seem to get it to work.

Boiled down I essentially try passing a Map as a delegate to a closure, but the syntax keeps alluring me.

As an example, consider this:

```
def map = [:]

map.with {
    example1 = 123
    //exam-ple2 = 123
    //'exam-ple3' = 123
    //(exam-ple4) = 123
    exam.ple5 = 123
    //'exam.ple6' = 123
}
```

Example 1 is fine, key equals value and easy readable. Examples 2 and 4 are according to the compiler a binary expression and won't compile. Examples 3 and 6 are constant expressions and won't compile. Example 5 will compile, but generate a NPE at runtime.

I can use workarounds like passing the Map as an argument to the closure, which gives me example 3 and 6, but the verbosity of it annoys me.

Does anybody have any ideas how to neatly DSL a property map?

BTW: I call the DSL from java not groovy, so tricks on the parsing side has to be java :)

**UPDATE 1** : After the inital comments and answers..

So the script is evaluated by a GroovyShell as a DelegatingScript, where the delegate is a Java object. The closure contains properties from `.properties` files, that needs to be defined in different context, e.g.

```
env {
  server-name=someHost1
  database.name=someHost2
  clientName=someHost3
}
```

The delegating (Java) object would read this block as

```
public void env(Closure closure) {
  Map map = new HashMap();
  closure.setDelegate(map);
  closure.setResolveStrategy(Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY);
  closure.call();
  ... do something with map...
```

}

Now the user (i.e. not me) will probably copy from the original property files into the script and change the names, hence I would rather they could do it without having to edit too much as it is bound to cause typos..

As I stated I has also example 3 and 6 covered as well, but yes, Tim, I forgot the implicit it :)

For now I have changed the format to a string, so the DSL writes something like

```
env '''
  server-name=someHost1
  database.name=someHost2
  clientName=someHost3
'''
```

That is, using a multi-line string instead of a closure, and then read the string and using a standard java.util.Properties:

```
public void env(String envString) {
  Properties properties = new Properties;
  properties.load(new StringReader(envString))
  ....etc
```

}

And although this works, the mix of having closures and multi-line string is the only downside for now.

Comment: can you explain : 'the parsing side has to be java' ?
since an internal groovy DSL relies on the groovy syntax parser
like map elements assignations here, how will you parse it with Java ???
and if you call groovy, won't this be done on the groovy side anyway ?

Comment: `it.'exam-ple2' = 123`

Answer (score 2):

In a map declaration, Groovy parses identifiers such as `example1` and `example2` as **string keys** to a map:

```
[ example1: 1, example2: 2 ]
```

In the `.with{}` context, it probably uses a [`setProperty(property, value)`](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.br/2009/10/groovy-goodness-getting-and-setting.html) mechanism.

---

But your case features expressions `exam.ple` and `exam-ple`. Those expressions have precedence, thus, Groovy will try to resolve them first (with probably something like `exam.getProperty('ple')` and `exam.minus(ple)`, respectively).

You have some syntactic alternatives, but you will have to make it clear to Groovy what are supposed to be string keys and what are other expressions:

```
def map = [
    'exam.ple4' : 4, // direct map declaration
    example5 : 5 // unambiguous key declaration: no quotes needed 
]

map.with {
    example1 = 1
    put 'exam.ple2', 2 // ambiguous, needs quotes
    it.'exam-ple3' = 3 // as per @TimYates suggestion
}

assert map['exam-ple3'] == 3
assert map.'exam.ple2' == 2
assert map['exam.ple4'] == 4
assert map.example5 == 5 // again, no quotes needed for key
```